# RewriteRule to new URL and internally rewrite to old one

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My goal is to redirect users from these paths:

```
/foo/index.php
/foo/
```

To

```
/index
```

And have `/index` load the original content from `/foo/index.php`.

Is this possible in `.htaccess`?

So far I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(index\.php)?$ /index [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index$ /foo/index.php [QSA,L]
```

But this gets into an infinite redirection loop. I thought adding a `RewriteCond` for the URI would help, but from the [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond):

> **Note:** Conditions are being processed after the pattern of the `RewriteRule` has matched.

So apparently `RewriteCond` won't be of much use in my use case.

Looking through the [Rewrite Flags docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags), the `S` flag seems to be what I'm looking for:

> This flag forces the rewriting engine to skip the next num rules in sequence, if the current rule matches. Use this to make pseudo if-then-else constructs: The last rule of the then-clause becomes skip=N, where N is the number of rules in the else-clause.

So I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^index$ /foo/index.php [QSA,L,S=1]
RewriteRule ^foo/(index\.php)?$ /index [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Though, as I have the `L` flag, the `S` flag seems a little redundant. Nevertheless, the logic seems correct in my view, though this is still in an infinite redirection loop.

Right now I'm using an workaround with PHP. First, Apache internally rewrites the new URL to the old one and then in the PHP I check if the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` matches the new format in the beginning of the script, otherwise ensue a 301 redirect to the new URL.

Though, I'd like to know whether this possible to do with `.htaccess` solely? Or if anyone can explain how/why I'm getting an infinite loop with the rewrite rules above I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that the rules are in a `.htaccess` file, and as [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) say, this file is reparsed after every rewite loop, letst it might have been applicable to a `.htaccess` in a different directory. Thus your `L` flags are all in vain.

I have looked around, and if you really cannot place your rewrite rules in the main apache config, I can offer the following kludge: because the Server-Variables `THE_REQUEST` is not updated between the rewrite runs, one can conclude the "browser visible URL" from there and prevent rewriting in that case:

```
# external redirect to /index (unless browser already shows /index plus query params)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^\w+\ /index(\?.*)?\ HTTP/1..$
RewriteRule ^foo/(index\.php)?$ /index [R=301,QSA,L]

# internal redirect for /index
RewriteRule ^index$ /foo/index.php [QSA,L]
```

I thought there is also another variable that remains unchanged, but right now I cannot find it. Maybe someone else ?

Comment: +1, the only logical explanation, as you've said, would be that `L` does not actually end the rewriting but rather start a new rewrite loop? Though, if I put these on the main conf as you've said, would it fix the issue? Going to test now.

Comment: Oh yes, I should've read the full `L` flag documentation before. I've updated your regex to match `/index` always at the start of the request path name: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^\w+\ /index(?:\?.*)?` it works nicely for now, thanks.

Comment: Also, to be more specific, instead of negating the new format, we can try to match the old one: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /foo/.*` - matching only `GET` requests as `POST` data would be lost in case of redirection, so POST urls are still functional with the old URL making it easy to spot and update internal links if POST requests are concerned. The `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}` matching a directory is also useful if redirecting all urls from inside the given path to the root, but that's out of the scope of the question, never mind it. `=]`